# doctrine to count one to many in query

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity Shop and Shop has many InstagramShopPicture, the relationship is as follows:

```
 /**
     * @Exclude()
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="InstagramShopPicture", mappedBy="shop", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"created" = "DESC"})
     */
    protected $userPictures;
```

I have the following query, and I need to find shops that have 4 or more pictures:

```
  $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('s')
                  ->from("AppMainBundle:InstagramShop", 's')
                  ->innerJoin('s.userPictures', 'p')
                  ;

      $query->andHaving('COUNT(s.userPictures) >= 4');
```

why doesn't this work? What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine uses SQL, so you need to do as you'd on SQL, using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

Also, you need to specify a field for the `COUNT`, such as `p.id`, not an alias.

Link explaining `HAVING`: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php